# How to get updated $refs on dynamically created component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My amount of components depends on array quantity, so when i add new item to array, it should create new component.

When new component is created i want to get reference on it, and that's where i have a misunderstanding. Last added component is `undefined` when i try to get it.

But, if i trying to get reference on it after some time, it work. I guess it's because of asynchronous, but i'm not sure.

Why this is happening and if there a way to avoid using `setTimeout`?

```
<div id="app">
    <button @click="addNewComp">add new component</button>
    <new-comp
        v-for="compId in arr"
        :ref="`components`"
        :index="compId"
        ></new-comp>
    </div>
  <script type="text/x-template " id="compTemplate">
    <h1> I am a component {{index}}</h1>
</script>
```

---

```
Vue.component("newComp",{
  template:"#compTemplate",
  props:['index']
})
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    arr:[1,2,3,4]
  },
  methods:{
    addNewComp:function(){
      let arr = this.arr;
      let components = this.$refs.components;
      arr.push(arr.length+1);
      console.log("sync",components.length);
      console.log("sync",components[components.length-1])
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("async",components.length);
        console.log("async",components[components.length-1])
      }, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/Halws/pen/VxKjgy)

Comment: I am unsure what your problem is, but maybe you're looking for the `updated` lifecycle?

Comment: @A.Lau yes, that helped, thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ref`s, and `$refs`, are not reactive.

If you want to pick up the updated value, you should wait until the next render cycle updates the DOM.

Instead of `setTimeout` you should use [`Vue.nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick):

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    arr:[1,2,3,4]
  },
  methods:{
    addNewComp:function(){
      let arr = this.arr;
      let components = this.$refs.components;
      arr.push(arr.length+1);
      console.log("sync",components.length);
      console.log("sync",components[components.length-1])
      Vue.nextTick(() => {                                         // changed here
        console.log("async",components.length);
        console.log("async",components[components.length-1])
      });                                                          // changed here
    }
  }
})
```

And this is not a "hack", this is the proper way of doing it. From [the official API docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick):

> #### Vue.nextTick( [callback, context] )
>
> - **Arguments:**
>
>   - `{Function} [callback]`
>   - `{Object} [context]`
> - **Usage:**
>
>   Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle.
>   Use it immediately after you've changed some data to wait for the DOM
>   update.
>
>   ```
>     // modify data
>     vm.msg = 'Hello'
>     // DOM not updated yet
>     Vue.nextTick(function () {
>       // DOM updated
>     })
>
>     // usage as a promise (2.1.0+, see note below)
>     Vue.nextTick()
>       .then(function () {
>         // DOM updated
>       })
>   ```

Comment: Please can someone define 'reactive' in the context of '$refs'? Because when changes to dom/js objects can be gotten (albeit maybe a little bit later), doesn't that qualify for being reactive? (because right now, being 'reactive' seems to mean that the changes are communicated IMMEDIATELY rather than a little but later)

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere "reactive" means you can use it in computed, watch, and any other API that expects a reactive property. You can't do any of that with $refs.

Comment: @DamilolaOlowookere Reactive props trigger updates in those that depend on them whenever it changes. E.g. a property `x` in `data` is reactive, meaning when it is used in the template, if `x` changes, the template is re-rendered immediatelly. If there is a computed property `y` that uses `x`, when `x` changes, `y` is recalculated immediatelly.