# Why does the vue documentation say refs are not reactive when indeed they are

Tags: vue.js

A quote from [the vue official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) states that

> $refs...are not reactive.

However, I have used such refs in templates and they are indeed reactive, and even in methods, computed props, and watchers (as long as you access it after being mounted). Several third party vue libraries [e.g. this one](https://lian-yue.github.io/vue-upload-component/#/documents) also provides features that use/depend on the reactivity of refs.

Can someone please clarify what the official doc meant by refs not being reactive please?

Comment: When there are linked dependencies to $refs in a component, a change in the dependent attribute's data wont trigger a rerender in the $ref until the DOM is mounted again. Here is an example of this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040027/how-to-get-updated-refs-on-dynamically-created-component-in-vue

Comment: @I'mOnlyVueman your comment suggests that being 'reactive' only applies to UI states (thus you said 'trigger a rerender'), whereas the state of the data is already persisted - it is simply a matter of waiting till the next DOM update. Does such "delay" qualify for not being reactive? (I just want to get a hang on the true meaning of objects being 'reactive')

Comment: My understanding is that reactive, at least in the Vue sense of the word, means that the DOM will perform tree-shaking to update the specific data element that needs an update, while leaving the rest of the virtual DOM as it is. So in the case of $refs the virtual DOM will not perform this update process, despite being sent updated data, because $refs isn't recognized in the Vue tree-shaking process. So instead the $refs will update once the entire virtual DOM is rerendered. May be worth having an expert confirm or revise that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what it means for something to be reactive in the context of the Vue framework. Sure, you are able to access the value of the `$refs` object after they have been set when the component is mounted, but that does not mean that the object is reactive.

When data is reactive, it means that changes to the value of that data will trigger a "reaction" from some part of the component that depends on that data's value, such as re-rendering the template, recalculating a computed variable, or triggering a watcher.

[Read through the documentation on reactivity.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

---

Here's an example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log('$refs.foo in mounted', this.$refs.foo);  
  },
  watch: {
    '$refs.foo':{
      immediate: true,
      handler(value) {
        console.log('$refs.foo watcher', value);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div ref="foo"></div>
  <div v-if="$refs.foo">
    If $refs.foo was reactive, the template would update and you would see this message
  </div>
</div>
```

In that example, you can see that the watcher for `$refs.foo` initially logs that the value of `$refs.foo` is `undefined`. This makes sense because the watcher has fired before the component has mounted, so the properties of the `$refs` object haven't been set yet. Then, in the `mounted` hook, we see that the value of `$refs.foo` has been set as expected.

If `$refs` was reactive, we would then see the template update, because the `v-if="$refs.foo"` directive would have evaluated to `true`. We would also see the watcher fire again after the value of `$refs.foo` was set, logging that new value of `$refs.foo`. However, since `$refs` is not reactive, neither of those things happen.