# this.$refs always empty or undefined in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ref

I am new to Vue and am trying to use $refs to grab some elements in the DOM from a sibling component (for very basic purposes, just to get their heights, etc.), and I'm doing so in a computed.

No matter what I try, `this.$root.$refs` either always comes back undefined or as an empty object, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

In a parent component, I have:

```
<template>
<ComponentA />
<ComponentB />
</template>
```

In component A I have:

```
<template>
  <div id="user-nav">
   <div ref="nav-container">
    <slot />
   </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I just try to see if I can access this in ComponentB by console logging

```
 console.log(this.$root.$refs);
```

in that component's mounted function.

But I keep getting an empty object.

Can you just not access things across sibling components like this???

Comment: `$refs` are local to that component, other components (even children) don't have access.

Comment: Is there any way to scope them globally??

Comment: @MattAft yes they do.

Comment: @George I guess I should've been more clearer but I meant `this.$refs` would only be refs local to that component. As you mentioned below, there's ways you can access other component's refs but I agree that it's not a recommended approach.

Comment: @MattAft ahhh, re-reading your comment with that explanation makes it super clear what you meant (the first time)!

Answer (score 7):

You might have already solved this, but just to answer this Q:

I had a similar problem and it seems that this happens because the function is being called before Vue has had time to replace the root DOM with its own version. What you can do to fix this is to create a `mounted` life-cycle hook and call the function there.

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sayHi: 'Hello World',
  },
  mounted: function() { // The hook. Here, Vue has already worked its magic.
    console.log('YOUR ELEMENT ----> ', this.doSomething())
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething: function() {
      return this.$refs['nav-container']
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span ref="nav-container">{{ sayHi }}</span>
</div>
```

I found the solution [here.](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-this-refs-key-returns-undefined-when-it-really-is/1226)

Comment: Refs still empty

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I was using `this.$refs` in computed property. I just **got rid of computed properties and used methods** and everything started to work properly because $refs are not reactive as mentioned for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927707/why-does-the-vue-documentation-say-refs-are-not-reactive-when-indeed-they-are) and [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/this-ref-el-in-computed-property-not-reactive/14216)

Answer (score 2):

This might not be an answer to your particular problem but I discovered that another reason for `$refs` being empty is that the component on which it is defined has not created/mounted yet. Probably due to the lazy rendering Vue uses.

I had a set of tabs, one of which was the one I had a "ref=" in, and if I did not visit that tab then `$refs` was empty. But íf I first visited the tab then the ref was set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, the problem you have is that you don't actually have any refs on your parent component.

**I do not recommend doing this anyway** either use vuex, an eventbus or $emit

```js
Vue.component('componentA', {
  template: '<div><span ref="ref-inside-a">You\'re in A!</span></div>',
  methods:{
  log(){
  console.log('Hello from a')
  }
  }
})

Vue.component('componentB', {
  props: ['ball'],
  template: '<div><span>This is B!</span></div>',
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$refs['a'].log()    
    console.log(this.$root.$refs['a'].$refs['ref-inside-a'])
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component-a ref="a"></component-a>
  <component-b ref="b"></component-b>

</div>
```

Comment: But all I need to do is get the height of some elements, and grab an array of elements to iterate over...I don't understand how $emit would work since there is no event.

Comment: @bjorkland You can create ref for component-a in the parent and pass the data you need down as a prop in component-b. Children are meant to be isolated from eachother, either use a central state or pass information from a parent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the cause was another one:

I had a `v-if` condition on the referenced element. So at the time of mounting the element was not rendered because the condition was still false.

After 3 hours of looking for the cause for the problem, it was so obvious.

```
<template>
  <sub-component v-if="showCondition" ref="componentName">
    <div>someContent</div>
    <div>someMoreContent</div>
  </sub-component> 
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  private showCondition = false; // set to true after a REST request
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs); // this was empty
  }
}
</script>
```

This problem can be solved by moving the v-if to an additional template element inside the referenced component.

```
<template>
  <sub-component ref="componentName">
    <template v-if="showCondition">
      <div>someContent</div>
      <div>someMoreContent</div>
    </template>
  </sub-component>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs); // now 'componentName' is available
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The problem can also be solved by changing v-if to v-show (if appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I faced this problem in 2 situations

1- `mounted` hook was inside `methods` which is worst typo

2- `ref` was inside a `v-for` loop which can not really be initialized without for loop being started in my case the for loop array was empty

Answer (score -1):

In my specific case the

```
this.$refs
```

part referenced to several components. Accessing a specific component by reference was possible:

```
this.$refs[componentName]
```

To access a specific field of the component above I had to select the first observable:

```
this.$refs[componentName][0].someFieldToBeSelected -> this works
this.$refs[componentName].someFieldToBeSelected -> this fails
```

.